# There is a problem with deleting many to many association

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
@entity
@table(name = "users")
public class User {

@Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_following",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_following_id")})
private List<User> following;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})
@JoinTable(name = "user_followers",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_follower_id")})
private List<User> followers;

//some other fields, getters and setters

public void follow(User user) {
    following.add(user);
    user.acceptFollower(this);
}

public void acceptFollower(User user) {
    followers.add(user);
}
}
```

We have three tables:

- users
- user_following
- user_followers

Imagine having this entity and you are implementing following & followers functionality.
We have to users - rick & tom.

```
User rick = new User(1, "rick");
User tom = new User(2, "tom");
rick.follow(tom);
```

After calling method - rick.follow(tom);
We will populate our tables in the following way

Table - "users"

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rick |
| 2 | tom |

Table - "user_following"

| user_id | user_following_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

Table - "user_followers"

| user_id | user_follower_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |

So far, everything works just great but the problem starts when i try to delete users.

For example:

userRepository.deleteById(1)

JPA gives an error -
update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk1yg7xqw2kfx6n2196o0gr3obc" on table "user_followers"
Подробности: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "user_followers".

JPA cannot delete because it generates a wrong sql.

```
Hibernate: 
   select
       user0_.id as id1_5_,
       user0_.first_name as first_na5_5_,
   from
       users user0_ 
   where
       user0_.username=?
Hibernate: 
   delete 
   from
       user_followers 
   where
       user_id=?
Hibernate: 
   delete 
   from
       user_following 
   where
       user_id=?
Hibernate: 
   delete 
   from
       users 
   where
       id=?
```

I want to delete user - rick whose id = 1

The error happens due to wrong sql.
When we delete user - 'rick',
we first delete 'rick' from "user_following" and "user_followers" tables.

Look at the this statement.

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_followers 
    where
        user_id=?
```

The error happens due to this statement because the
user we are deleting corresponds to the (user_following_id) column of the "user_followers" table,
not "user_id" column.

The right sql statement must be:

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        user_followers 
    where
        user_following_id=?
```

Is there a way how to fix this?

Comment: In Following and Followers List field try to add remove in cascade operation name list

Comment: In this case, it will remove both users - tom and rick. But i want to delete only rick

Comment: Try to replace **@ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})** by **@ManyToMany(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE})**

Comment: Adding cascade = REMOVE doesnt solve the problem, since it removes both users.
While using ManyToMany, it preferable to avoid using cascade=Delete

Answer (score 0):

Do not create `user_followers` as a table, instead create it as a *view* on the table `user_following`. The view definition merely reverses the column names. I do not know your obscurification manager so I will just supply the needed SQL. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=01e0a65587406a7393c9b3879d25a562)).

```
create table users( id    integer primary key 
                  , name  text 
                  ) ; 
                 
 create table user_following( user_id   integer 
                                        references users(id) 
                                        on delete cascade 
                            , user_following_id integer 
                                        references users(id) 
                                        on delete cascade
                            , constraint  user_following_pk 
                                          primary key (user_id,user_following_id)
                            ) ; 
                            
create view user_followers as 
       select user_following_id as user_id 
            , user_id           as user_follower_id
  from user_following;
```